# To show the function $\frac{1}{x\log x}$ is continuous on $[2,\infty)$

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

I want to know that how can i show that the function $\displaystyle f(x)= \frac{1}{x\log x}$ continuous? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $f$ and $g$ are continuous on a particular interval and $g(x) \neq 0$ for any $x$ on that interval, then $\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}$ is continuous on that interval.

$1$ is continuous on that interval. $x\log x$ is continuous and nonzero on that interval. Hence $\frac{1}{x\log x}$ is continuous.

Answer (score 1):

I think function is continuous from (1,∞).